# How WordPress autosave can save plugin fields?

Tags: plugins, custom-field, metabox, autosave

**Setup:**

- WordPress Add/Edit Post/Page
- A plugin that have its own postbox with several hidden fields.

**Issue:**

How these custom hidden fields can be saved along with the other post data within the **Autosave** feature?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just made a plugin that needed to be autosaved, so i started to dig into the code. I did now that it have to be trigged by some javascript so started to look into the console in Chrome when autosave fires. I then saw that `autosave.js` looks for a class `tags-input` in admin-filters.php you can see the comment:

```
// NOTE: the class "tags-input" allows to include the field in the autosave $_POST (see autosave.js)
```

So i just added the class `tags-input` to my hidden fields and it now saves when autosave fires!

Here is my example: `<input type="hidden" class="tags-input" name="key" value="value" />`

**Update:**

Now you have to add your data by your own ajax function. (add a new js-file and include in footer. admin_enqueue_scripts)

```
jQuery(document).ajaxSend(function(e, x, a) {
    var data = 1;
    a.data += '&' + jQuery.param( {test_data: data} );
});
```

And the saving:

```
add_action('save_post', 'autosave_save_custom');

function autosave_save_custom( $post ) {
    if( wp_is_post_autosave($post) && isset( $_POST['test_data'] ) ) {
        $test_data = intval( $_POST['test_data'] );
        $post_id = $post->ID;
        update_metadata( $post->post_type, $post_id, 'test_data', $test_data );
    }
}
```

Comment: Neat, but that its safe to do? I mean, when you restores the autosave its doesn't get those values and to set the tags?

Comment: I searched and didn't found any mention to `tags-input` there so I think can be used :D However, had you any issues regarding this?

Comment: There are other plugins that using this method, such as Polylang. And no your values will not get the tags. I think the ajax-request looks for the class tags-input to build the data posted to the database.

Comment: He..What version of WP are you using? I checked a WP 3.5.2 installation and it have the code you say except the comment :( which is bad indication. In a WP 3.6 installation It has the code...**commented!** :O with a message that reads: `/*
 // We haven't been saving tags with autosave since 2.8... Start again?
 $('.the-tags').each( function() {
  data[this.name] = this.value;
 });
 */`

Comment: Anyway, was a good suggestion but do you have another way? This one seems inconsistent and unsafe since WP team removed that feature.

Comment: That will do it :) Just is missing a check to fire the inner callback function only when the autosave is in process and not on every AJAX request a plugin can made.

Comment: I will mark you answer as accepted since its a valid answer :) but I finally managed to get this working by doing my own AJAX autosave handler separated from WordPress autosave, this way I think is more reliable and less error prone on WordPress updates.